# Android WifiP2pManager createGroup always fail with BUSY state

Tags: android, wifip2p

I use the following code to create a WifiP2p group

```
manager.requestGroupInfo(channel, new WifiP2pManager.GroupInfoListener() {
    public void onGroupInfoAvailable(WifiP2pGroup group){
        if (group != null) {
            manager.removeGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    manager.createGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int reason) {
                            Debug.d("" + reason);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    Debug.d("" + reason);
                }
            });
        } else {
            manager.createGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    Debug.d("" + reason);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

It always fails with the reason code BUSY. I ran it in the debug mode and found that the WifiP2pGroup object returned is always null. Yet it fails with BUSY reason. I create and keep the WifiP2pManager and Channel objects in the Application class and uses them throughout the application as a singleton. Could that be the issue? I couldn't find an answer online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the source of the issue. **My WIFI was turned off**. I used WifiManager to turn WIFI on and now it is creating the group as expected.